# SharePoint calendar sharing on iPhone and iPad

Tags: sharepoint-designer, calendar, apple-ios

I want to connect SharePoint calendar with iPhone and iPad. This calendar is used by my colleague.
Is there any possibility to add this calendar to my iPhone and iPad?

How I can add this calendar?

Best regards.

Comment: the link for bamboosolutions does not work.. does anyone have the HOW-TO printed out or so to share with me? regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two may be helpful to you -

- [How to Sync your iPhone/iPad with a SharePoint Calendar](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/mashpoint/archive/2010/10/07/how-to-synch-your-iphone-ipad-with-a-sharepoint-calendar.aspx) (programmatic via REST API)
- [SharePlus for iOS](http://www.sharepointoniphone.com/) (commercial app from Infragistics - includes a free lite version)

You may want to also explore the iTunes App store for more commercial apps (some are free).